# VBA Excel User Form Output to Txt File

Tags: vba, file, excel, userform

I am trying to create a user form that takes user input and prints to a text file. I know the VBA scripting functions to print, store strings etc. BUT I'm new to userforms. How do you limit input and output to a text file? Add to that same file?

INPUT AND OUTPUT:

[image: inputandoutput]

I would need to have this variety of

**KEY FEATURES:**

1. **Limited Entry:** XXXX means only enter 4 characters (The notepad file can only be certain characters long
2. **Multiple Entries:** After a set of records is entered to the text file, their values are stored and another input is allowed. Also the new entries have to be written to the same file on the next line
3. **Space if left blank:** If XXXX is left blank then four " " should be printed instead.

If you have part or all of these answers I'd like to hear from you!

---------------------------Edited with Adding Code-----------------------------

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

'Fill Eggs
With Eggs
    .AddItem "Eggs"
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CreateList_Click()

Dim myFile As String, myString As String
myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1

Dim fourChars As String * 4
fourChars = Milk.Value

myString = Eggs.Value + Milk.Value + Bread.Value

Print #1, myString

Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1

End Sub
```

So the above code launches this screen:

Comment: What have you already tried? What code do you already have?

Comment: You can declare a fixed width string in VBA `Dim fourChars As String * 4`

Comment: I was having intermittent Internet so it looks like my code didn't post. I'm on my phone today. I'll edit tomorrow. Y all the downvotes? Question seems clear?

Comment: @HaukeP. I added my code. Was busy over the weekend. Should have added it earlier sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox have `MaxLength` property. Default is set to `0` which does not limit character entry.
To limit the entry into a certain number, just change the value of this property to that number.

[image: sample]

Now for replacing the `XXXX` with blank(if none or less than 4 is entered), take on SO advise in the comments.

```
Dim fourChars As String * 4
fourChars = TextBox1.Value
MsgBox Len(fourChars) ' will always return 4
```

Comment: The max length works perfectly thanks! The four blanks if nothing is entered doesnt quite work. Should I put a If loop?

Comment: Do u put the code in the text box command or in the userform initialize command?

Comment: I guess to clarify - If nothing is entered in a box it has to give x blank characters where x is the number of characters that should have been entered. So if the program is expecting (4) XXXX and nothing is entered - it needs print 4 blanks "    " in its place.

Comment: This worked! : If Len(Milk.Value) = 0 Then
Milk.Value = Space(4)
End If